# LIKE clause in Sybase/SAP ASE trimmed at the end?

Tags: sap-ase, sql-like

The emp table below has no ENAME ending in three spaces. However, the following SQL statement behaves like the clause is trimmed at the end (like a '%' pattern), because it returns all records:

```
select ENAME from dbo.emp where ENAME like '%   '
```

I tried many other database platforms (including SQL Server, SQL Anywhere, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL etc), I've seen this happening only in Sybase/SAP ASE (version 16). Is this a bug or is it "by design"? Nothing specific found in the [online spec](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug84.htm) in this regard.

I'm looking for a generic fix, to apply some simple transformation to the pattern and return what is expected from any other platform. Without knowing in advance what data type the field is or what kind of data it holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the VARCHAR semantics in ASE, which will always strip leading spaces from a value before operating on it. This is applied to the string '%   ' before it is used, since that is a VARCHAR value by definition. This is indeed a particular semantic of ASE.

Now, you could try working around this by using the [ ] wildcard to match a space, but there are some things to be aware of. First, the column being matched (ENAME) must be CHAR, not VARCHAR, otherwise any trialing spaces will have been stripped as well before they were stored.  Assuming the column is CHAR, then using a pattern '%[ ][ ][ ]' unfortunately still does not appear to work. I think there may be some trailing-space-stripping still happening here.

The best way to work around this is to use an artificial end-of-field delimiter which will not occur in the data, e.g.

```
ENAME||'~EOF~' like '%   ~EOF~'
```

This works. But note that the column ENAME must still be CHAR rather than VARCHAR.

Comment: Thanks, RobV. I'll vote this up and mark as the answer, but I am still not happy with the fix. I'm looking for something more generic, if possible (see the end of my edited question).

Comment: I don't think there is a better fix. The ASE semantics around trailing spaces in VARCHAR expressions kick in before anything else does.

Answer (score 0):

Like behavior is somehow documented in [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug86.htm) .

For VARCHAR columns this will never work because ASE removes the trailing spaces

For CHAR it depends how do you insert the data.. in a char(10) column , if you insert 2 characters , ASE will add 8 blank spaces after the 2 characters to make them 10 .. so when you query , you will get this 2 characters entry as part of the result set because it includes more than 3 trailing spaces..

If this is not a problem for you, instead of like you can use char_index () which will count the trailing spaces and won't truncate them as like, so you could write something like :

```
select ENAME from dbo.emp where char_index('   ',ENAME) >0
```

Or you can  calculate the trailing spaces , then check if your 3 spaces come after that or not , like :

```
select a from A 
where charindex('    ',a) > (len(a) - len(convert (varchar(10) , a)))
```

Now *again*, this will get you more rows than expected if the data were inserted in a non-uniform count, but will work perfectly if you know exactly what to search for.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT ename from dbo.emp  where RIGHT(ENAME ,3) = '      '